# laravel horizonで jobの監視をしているが、ずっと Jobs Past Hour は 0 のまま

Tags: laravel

localhost で cronの動作を確認するためにHorizonをインストールしました。

Laravelの公式サイト [Laravel 10.x Laravel Horizon](https://readouble.com/laravel/10.x/ja/horizon.html) を参考に。

Jobにて1分ごとに処理を行っています。

```
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\UpdateMonitoringJob)->everyMinute();
$schedule->job(new \App\Jobs\PendingMonitoringJob)->everyMinute();
```

この処理は問題なく動作しており、cronも正しく実行されています。

しかし、Horizonを見るとprocessは1で、何時間経過しても `Jobs Past Hour` は 0のまま。
`Completed Jobs` もずっと `There aren't any jobs.` になっています。
`Pending jobs, Silenced jobs, Failed jobs` も`There aren't any jobs.`

### 動作チェック

horizonは正常に動作をしていることを確認しています

```
sail artisan horizon:snapshot
Metrics snapshot stored successfully.

sail artisan horizon:status
Horizon is running.
```

config/queue.php

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
```

しかしながら、見た限りでは2時間を経過しても動作記録が取られていないようです。
これは何が原因でしょうか？またどのように対応するべきでしょうか？
アドバイスを頂けると嬉しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]